# Existence and Uniqueness of lifting Hele-Shaw problem

Tags: differential-equations, fluid-dynamics, existence-theorems, uniqueness-theorems, partial-hyperbolicity

I am researching for the existence and uniqueness of solutions for the equation in figure below

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/raI8h.jpg)

$$\nabla\cdot u = \frac{\dot b(t)}{b(t)} \text{ in }\Omega(t) \tag{1}$$

The kinematic boundary condition is
$$-\frac{b^2(t)}{12\mu} \frac{\partial p}{\partial n}=V_n \text{ on }\partial\Omega(t)\tag{2}$$

Comment: Have you done a search for existing results in this direction?

Comment: yes, there is no result about existence yet